# Как вставить имя метода внутри шаблонов кода в PHPStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, symfony, ide

Использую PHPStorm. Я хочу использовать имя метода из PHP класса в переменной шаблона Live. Но я не нашел функции для этого на странице [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/template-variables.html](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/template-variables.html#predefined_functions)

Для JS есть метод jsMethodName(), а для PHP не нашёл. Есть ли способ вставить имя метода в шаблон?

```
/**
 * @return Response
 * @Route(path="/profile", name="profile")
 */
public function profile(): Response
{
    return $this->render("app/profile/$HOW_TO_INSERT_METHOD_NAME_HERE$.html.twig");
}
```

Comment: руками вписать например. в чем суть ваших изысканий?

Comment: Руками можно всё вписать, но с шаблонами работать удобнее. Интересно, почему функция phpClassName() есть, а для метода нет.

Comment: https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/view.html  то что вам нужно, однако в best practice не рекомендуют.